# Overlay ggR raster on ggRGB

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I am trying to overlay a raster with ggR on a RGB plotted with ggRGB. Parts of the ggR raster have NA values (or this could be also zeros) which should be transparent and show the underlying RGB raster. Any help on how to achieve this?

```
library(RStoolbox)
library(tidyverse)

data(rlogo)
im <- rlogo[[1]]
im[im>100]=NA
im[im<=100]=1
ggRGB(rlogo, r=1, g=2, b=3)+ggR(im,ggLayer=T,geom_raster=T)+ 
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(1),na.value="transparent")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the "transparent" that is the problem.

```
library(RStoolbox)
library(tidyverse)

data(rlogo)
im <- rlogo[[1]]
im[im>100]=NA
im[im<=100]=1
ggRGB(rlogo, r=1, g=2, b=3)+ggR(im,ggLayer=T,geom_raster=T)+ 
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(1),na.value=NA)
```

That should do the trick